# Why Swift's malloc/MemoryLayout.size take/return signed integers?

Tags: swift, memory-management, malloc, sizeof, memory-layout

```
public func malloc(_ __size: Int) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer!

@frozen public enum MemoryLayout<T> {
    public static func size(ofValue value: T) -> Int
    ...
```

When in C `malloc`/`sizeof` take/return `size_t` which is unsigned?
Isn't Swift calling libc under the hood?

EDIT: is this the reason why? https://qr.ae/pvFOQ6
They are basically trying to get away from C's legacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's calling the libc functions under the hood.

[The `StdlibRationales.rst` document](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/StdlibRationales.rst#size_t-is-unsigned-but-it-is-imported-as-int) in the Swift repo explains why it imports `size_t` as `Int`:

> Converging APIs to use `Int` as the default integer type allows users to write fewer explicit type conversions.
>
> Importing `size_t` as a signed `Int` type would not be a problem for 64-bit platforms. The only concern is about 32-bit platforms, and only about operating on array-like data structures that span more than half of the address space. Even today, in 2015, there are enough 32-bit platforms that are still interesting, and x32 ABIs for 64-bit CPUs are also important. We agree that 32-bit platforms are important, but the usecase for an unsigned `size_t` on 32-bit platforms is pretty marginal, and for code that nevertheless needs to do that there is always the option of doing a bitcast to `UInt` or using C.